# Get Related entries from Category besides the category of the entry itself

Tags: entry, category

I have two types of related entries for the current entry.
Category:

- Interviews -> Photographer
- Interviews -> Skateboarder
- Interviews -> Filmer
- Interviews -> Owner

I am now on an entry with the child category "Skateboarder".

At first i get entries of the same child category, so random entries of the childcategory "skateboarder".

With this:

```
{% set relatedCategory = craft.entries({
  section: 'news',
  relatedTo: entry.newsCategory.level(2),
  id: 'not ' ~ entry.id,
  order: 'RAND()',
  limit: 3  
}) %}
```

My second goal is now to get other entries from the parent category "Interviews" BESIDES the current childcategory (Skateboarder)..

So only random entries of the child categories Photographer, Filmer, Owner...

how do i get this? :)
thx!!!